# In words like able, or candle does the l function as a vowel and the e function as a consonant?

Tags: sounds, phonics

I was recently told as part of my THRASS (phonics program for primary schools) training that in words ending in -le such as able, crumple, candle etc that the letter l functions as a vowel with the schwa sound and the letter e functions as a consonant with the "L" sound. This seems counter-intuitive to me and I was wondering if it could be better explained by word origins?

Comment: The pronunciation is /ˈeɪb(ə)l/. You can see that the positional correspondence from letters in 'able' to phonemes in  /ˈeɪb(ə)l/ is 'a'→/eɪ/, 'b'→/b/, 'l'→/(ə)/, and 'e'→/l/. The word 'able' [comes from](https://www.etymonline.com/word/able#etymonline_v_48) Old French 'hable'.

Comment: The letters don't represent contrary sounds though. In the case of *able*, the spelling has drifted away from the phonetics. It's an error to say that the *l* functions as a vowel and the *e* functions as a consonant. Instead it's a kind of metathesis - the *l* and the *schwa* vowel switch position to form a syllable, a shift the spelling doesn't reflect.

Comment: There's just a schwa before the consonant *l* and the terminal *e* is silent. And no, nothing has changed its pronunciation or position. Also @TaliesinMerlin

Comment: Hi @mama see my comment above.